# Using Firebase / Pusher / Pubnub for to-fro push notifications between .Net Desktop application and web application

Tags: .net, winforms, firebase, pusher, pubnub

I am working on a system which has a .NET Desktop Winform application and a Web application (with REST APIs and HTML/JavaScript based UIs), I want to use one of the REST based hosted service (Firebase / Pusher / PubNub) to establish push notification based communication between these applications so that any changes done by a user (or an external systems) on either of the applications should be notified to another application instantaneously.

As per my understanding the hosted services mentioned above work with mechanisms like WebSockets which are more suited to browser based communication. Thus need to understand if above mentioned scenario could be dealt with using these REST based hosted services (Firebase / Pusher / PubNub).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebase, Pusher and PubNub all offer a REST/Web API that allow you to publish event/data and in some cases query state. All of these services also offer a real-time API for consuming and publishing data.

Firebase and Pusher try to use WebSockets and fallback to HTTP-based solutions. PubNub use purely HTTP-based connectivity. Although these are web technologies they are not tied to web browsers. These technologies just tended to be made available and used in browsers before other client technologies. For example, .NET 4.5 has a [WebSocket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, **all of these hosted service solutions are absolutely suitable for your scenario**.

- The most referred to .NET Firebase library is [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp).
- Pusher have [a number of .NET libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries#dotnet) that you could look at using
- PubNub also have [a number of .NET solutions](https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp)

If you decided that you didn't want to used a hosted service you could take a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) which is part of ASP.NET or [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/) which is a solid .NET solution. More information available in the [Real-time Web Technology Guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide).

Comment: Thanks leggetter for the inputs. Will try these out. Any comments in terms of parameters (usability, professional support, learning curve, production stability & performance) to choose one of these.

Comment: @SOUser - all three are professional and production grade platforms with dedicated support channels as well as a community of users. Usability - I'd say Pusher is the easiest to use (although I used to work there so my opinion my be biased). PubNub is also easy to use as a pubsub platform and Firebase has a slightly steeper learning curve as it's a data synchronisation platform. For performance see these [realtime latency stats](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/realtime-hosted-service-latency). In your use case you should be up an running in 10mins on any platform.

Comment: Hi leggetter,

Thanks for your help, I have created two .Net console applications (one with PusherServer, another with PusherClient). 

Looks like I am missing something on client app since, though I am able to connect server and send messages, I am not able to receive the messages in client app

Below are the client & server sample codes, please help me identify the problem with my client code

Comment: @SOUser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648566/pusher-based-server-client-messaging-between-net-console-applications not found

Comment: @Kiquenet Pusher and PubNub are hosted services. You can install their .NET libraries in any supporting environment. These libraries help you interact with their APIs, you don't install an "instance` of their service.

Comment: *Firebase, Pusher / PubNub*  are _hosted services_, requires `REST API`. *SignalR* is ***SELF host service***